# Full text search when words have the same start

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm new to full text search engine, I have a table filled with french and english words, but I'm having wierd issues when I try to implement the requests. The goal is to do a search engine with auto completion. Currently there the where are made with ILIKE but I heard that it's not 'scalable'

Let's say that I have a book table :

```
CREATE TABLE t_books (
    title TEXT
);

INSERT INTO t_books VALUES('Admin');
INSERT INTO t_books VALUES('Administratif');

INSERT INTO t_books VALUES('Adminare');-- no french words
INSERT INTO t_books VALUES('Admininids');
INSERT INTO t_books VALUES('Admin2');
```

When I run this query :

```
SELECT  b_id
FROM (
    SELECT title as b_id,
       to_tsvector('french',title) as document
     FROM   t_books
) p_search
WHERE p_search.document @@ to_tsquery('french','admin');
```

With the likes, I get all the 5 rows, but with this query this only returns "Admin".

However, it looks like it's works better with english words (those above are french and english, for example with the titles 'book','booking','booked'; when i'm looking up for book it returns the 3 rows.

http://rextester.com/RKNE72921

What is wrong there ? Is it a lack of french words in the dictionnary ?

Comment: Prefix match looks like `to_tsquery('french','admin:*')` -- BTW, if you only want to do a prefix match, no FTS is required. Just index `LOWER(title)` and use `LOWER(title) LIKE LOWER('Admin%')`: prefix `LIKE` searches can use the (default) btree index.

Comment: Also, your example with 'book', 'booking', and 'booked' works because these words are inflected from the same word: book. FTS is clever enough to be aware of this. But it cannot detect arbitrary prefixes.

Comment: Also (again :)) if your goal is auto completion, have a look at the [`pg_trgm` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) -- with it you could detect misspellings too.

Comment: Then 'Admin' and 'Administratif' are inflected from the same word isn't it ? A description will be added on this table, this contains a few words about the book. So I should be able to get rows based on the description word entered too (with highlights)

Comment: No, I don't think `Admin` is a complete, dictionary word in french (at least google translate does not know it either, it autocompletes to words, which start with `Administ...`). -- A description *may* require FTS, but please expand your question with the details & how do you want it to work.